# arguments in R CMD BATCH mode from Shell

Tags: r, shell

I want to call a R script from a Shell script with `R CMD BATCH --no-save --no-restore`.
How I can transfer a parameter (for example `$1`) from the Shell script into the R script?

Answer (score 2):

As I wrote elsewhere, the BATCH command acts a bit weird sometimes, so I just use the --file command directly:

```
R --slave --vanilla --file=myScript.R --args foo=2 bar=3 "s=string with spaces" > output.txt
```

...and then in `myScript.R` I use `args <- commandArgs(TRUE)` to get the extra arguments `foo` etc...